# Unable to load example database from "SQL Queries For Mere Mortals" into Oracle's SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to load in the example database for "sql queries for mere mortals" using the SQLScripts version of the example databases into Oracle SQL Developer but I keep getting this error:

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
>
> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
>
> ORA-01100: database already mounted
>
> 1501. 00000 -  "CREATE DATABASE failed"
>
> *Cause:    An error occurred during create database
>
> *Action:   See accompanying errors.

Is this a database error in my connection setup OR is there some SQL commands that need to be changed?

Comment: how are you creating the schema ? On Oracle should be CREATE USER <schema-name> IDENTIFIED BY <schema-password>; and then some GRANT on it

Comment: `create database` is something a DBA would run once when creating the database; in Oracle 'database' means something different to other platforms, and you might really want to be creating a schema. [According to this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/9780321444431/introduction/pref06lev1sec6) they are "SQL scripts that you can modify and use with any major database system" so you're expected to tweak them (but seems odd you're supposed to know how to do that!?). It looks like they came from SQL Server originally. Without seeing the actual scripts can't be more specific.

Comment: @AlexPoole: agree, probably OP just needs to create a schema, since we can assume he's already connected to the instance.

Comment: In SQLPlus I performed the CREATE USER/IDENTIFY BY, then established and confirmed a connection between Developer and the USER created. Example of the script is as follows: 'code' CREATE DATABASE BowlingLeagueExample
GO

use BowlingLeagueExample
GO

CREATE TABLE Bowler_Scores (
 MatchID smallint NOT NULL ,
 GameNumber smallint NOT NULL ,
 BowlerID smallint NOT NULL ,
 RawScore smallint NULL ,
 HandiCapScore smallint NULL ,
 WonGame bit NOT NULL 
) 
GO...

Comment: Well you'd need to replace `GO` with `/` for a start, and skip the `use` command. It says they were careful to make it generic, but that's pretty much impossible.  You might find someone has already tweaked the scripts for Oracle; that isn't something you can get done here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the fresh SQL scripts from their website (see the downloads link)  http://www.informit.com/store/sql-queries-for-mere-mortals-a-hands-on-guide-to-data-9780321992475.

You need to run the scripts that create the schema for you first, and than you can run the files that insert data and stuff into them.

There is a mySQL folder in the archive that you are going to download.

The creation failure could also have happened because you've already imported a schema of the same name, but you forgot to refresh the schemas, so its "hidden" from plain view.

*Edit:
Skipped over the Oracle part, here is a comparison table between mysql and oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#i1026408

Keep in mind though that mysql community is free; I think you should just download it and save the hassle, since you are using the software for learning purposes, you don't need to use any particular vendor's solution, like you normally would need to in a set production environment!

Comment: The challenge is converting it for Oracle.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I guess I skipped over the Oracle part; mysql community is free though, I'll update my post.